# Application Center starts with plain grey screen on iPhone 4S iOS 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

<---- snip ----->

I seem to be having an issue with the Application Center client on iOS 6.x.

It is strange because I am able to connect download the Application Center to the device but when I launch it I get a plain grey screen.

I see the following:

```
2013-02-06 08:42:56.445 IBMAppCenter241:3d0b Web resources integrity test is disabled.
2013-02-06 08:42:56.474 IBMAppCenter241:907 Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-02-06 08:42:57.931 IBMAppCenter241:907 LOG ondeviceready event dispatched
2013-02-06 08:42:57.934 IBMAppCenter241:907 {
                                                appVersionPref = "1.0";
                                                freeSpace = 6947221504;
                                                wlSkinLoaderChecksum = "(null)";
                                                wlSkinName = default;
                                            }
2013-02-06 08:42:57.953 IBMAppCenter241:907 LOG Application did not define an i18n messages object, skipping translation.
2013-02-06 08:42:57.954 IBMAppCenter241:907 LOG wlclient init started
2013-02-06 08:42:57.956 IBMAppCenter241:907 LOG Read cookies: null
2013-02-06 08:42:57.957 IBMAppCenter241:907 LOG CookieMgr read cookies: {}
2013-02-06 08:42:58.223 IBMAppCenter241:907 LOG before: app init onSuccess
2013-02-06 08:42:58.225 IBMAppCenter241:907 LOG after: app init onSuccess
2013-02-06 08:42:58.226 IBMAppCenter241:907 LOG wlclient init success
```

Just wondered if anyone had any ideas to the problem.

Worklight 5.0.5

<---- snap ----->

Please note: This issue was posted in [IBM developerworks forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14938616&#14938616) but is still not answered. I am in trouble with the same issue.

Thx4Help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the language of your phone set to English? If not then try to do this. If the mobile client works then it means that you are facing a known problem that we have fixed in 5.0.5.1 (see [IBM Worklight V5.0.5.1 and IBM Mobile Foundation V5.0.5.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034221)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't resolved the issue. Installed an fresh eclipse juno with 5.0.5.1 from market place. Phone set to English works, Phone set to German doesn't work.

Comment: @user2068917, And with 5.0.6.1?